# parsing xml - off by a node

Tags: xml, xpath, lxml

I am trying to parse the value from a Yahoo finance page. I used Chrome to inspect the element of interest (the current price of a stock) and used the xpath in this simple script:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VNQ?p=VNQ')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

print tree.xpath('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]/text()')
```

However, what I get is the text value from the next span tag. I've tried to alter the xpath that Chrome gives me to get the previous text value with no success. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Are you _sure_ all those hardcoded indexes are correct?

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: They are cut/paste from Chrome Copy Path with the desired text highlighted. The 2 things I don't understand are why it gives what appears to be the xpath to the text of the next span tag rather than the one highlighted. And second, assuming that Chrome gives an incorrect xpath, how do I alter it to get the right one (since it is very close).

Comment: The expected result is the Current price which of course varies constantly during market hours but if you go to the page in the script you will see the number that is in 36px type.

Comment: If anyone can tell me a better way to parse this webpage to get this (or another value), please tell me the right technique.

Comment: It returns the correct text for me, but the page is dynamic.  The number changes while I'm viewing it.  While I have it up on screen the text changes to values between 85.01 and 85.05.  What do you mean by "previous text value?"  The number is constantly changing.

Comment: If you run the script above, it returns the value of the $change and the %change (they are right next to the current price on the rendered page). If you use the Inspect feature of Firefox or Chrome there is a tag with the current price. But if you use Copy xpath to get the path it seems to point to the $ and % change and not to the current price. I also tried getting this value using BeautifulSoup but that failed in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the price you want you could take it from an easier place in the page. For instance the title html tag contains it. With a bit of string parsing, you'll get the right value. The value is always after the first space.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VNQ?p=VNQ')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

title = tree.xpath('//title/text()')[0]
value = title.split()[1]

print(value)
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried your script and got:

> python stack.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "stack.py", line 8, in <module>
>     value = int(title.split()[1]) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ':'

I will play with this some more.

Comment: Try without the Int(). Just updated the code in my response. Please accept my answer if this works.

Comment: >>> from lxml import html
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VNQ?p=VNQ')
>>> tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
>>> title = tree.xpath('//title/text()')[0]
>>> value = title.split()[1]
>>> print(value)
: